# Using static library that has pods dependency to Google Admob iOS SDK

Tags: ios, admob, static-libraries, cocoapods

I created a static library that includes my util classes(advertisement, date, network, etc.) and called that library UtilsLib. In UtilsLib podspec i give dependency to some libraries like Admob(6.8.0), google analytics(3.0.3), Toast(2.2) etc. Here is the UtilsLib podspec :

```
#
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "UtilsLib"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "Private static library for Ercans ios projects"

  s.description  = <<-DESC
                   A longer description of UtilsLib in Markdown format.

                   * BlockAlerts and ActionSheets
                   * GDataXML-HTML
                   * Admob
                   * Google Analytics
                   * MMDrawerController
                   * MMPickerView
                   * Reachability
                   * Toast
                   * UIDevice-Hardware
                   * ios-linechart
                   * objc-utils
                   DESC

  s.homepage     = "http://iosdeveloper61.blogspot.com.tr/"
  s.license      = "MIT (example)"
  s.author       = { "Ercan Celik" => "erceng@gmail.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "6.1"
  s.source_files  = "UtilsLib", "UtilsLib/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.public_header_files = "UtilsLib/**/*.h"
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.dependency 'UIDevice-Hardware', '~> 0.1.3'
  s.dependency 'Reachability', '~> 3.1.1'
  s.dependency 'BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets', '~> 1.0.6'
  s.dependency 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.4.0'
  s.dependency 'MMPickerView', '~> 0.0.1'
  s.dependency 'ios-linechart', '~> 1.2.0'
  s.dependency 'Toast', '~> 2.2'
  s.dependency 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  s.dependency 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK'

end
```

When i build the workspace of the UtilsLib, there is no error. Then i created a project and give dependency to UtilsLib in it's podfile like this :

```
platform :ios, "6.1"

pod 'UtilsLib', :path => '../../../UtilsLib'
```

The path of the UtilsLib is correct, i am sure. When i build the new workspace it gives the error below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGSizeFromGADAdSize", referenced from:
      +[AdUtils showAdMobBanner:] in libPods.a(AdUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPods.a(AdUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPods.a(AdUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPods.a(AdUtils.o)
  "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
      +[AdUtils showAdMobBanner:] in libPods.a(AdUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

AdUtils is a class in UtilsLib that uses google admob sdk. When i remove the admob sdk and so AdUtils class from UtilsLib there is no error in my new project.

Please help, i couldn't find any solution since yesterday :(